# Greater-than PowerShell operator giving inaccurate results

Tags: powershell, if-statement, operators

For some reason, when I debug - `$debug` is equal to 1, yet when the debugger hits `if(numUsers -gt 2)`, it enters the if block...

```
function numUsers()
    {@(query user /server:$server).Count - 1
    }

$debug = numUsers

if(numUsers -gt 2)
    {#true
    }
else
    {#Nothing
    }
```

Am I using the -gt operator properly? Am I missing something really obvious?

Appreciate any insight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-gt 2` are being seen as arguments to the `numUsers` call as written.

You can see that by looking at the value of `$args` in your `numUsers` function.

You need to tell powershell that you want to call `numUsers` on its own for this to work.

```
if ((numUsers) -gt 2) {
    "gt 2"
} else {
    "lt 2"
}
```

Comment: You don't need the $, just the parens, btw.